# PowerBi - Dax formula to get multiple same columns on the same table

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm very new to powerbi and dax and would like to seek some help or suggestions here.

How am I going to return the rows with exactly have match on other columns.
I want to return the highlighted data on the picture.
Or maybe I can have a new column with value of 1 for duplicate and 0 for not so I can return them all depending on it.

I'm trying to use `lookupvalue` but I don't know how to do it with multiple columns to return

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to
either create a `surrogateID` on-the-fly and utilize that in the calculation to let `DAX` return you the duplicates
or count the **`dates`** by **`PMT-val`** partition as in **`ALLEXCEPT`**.

**Calculated Column - using COUNTX**

```
isDup? =
VAR _surrogateID = 'Table'[PMTNo] & 'Table'[val] & 'Table'[date]
VAR _count =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTX ( 'Table', _surrogateID ) )
RETURN
    IF ( _count > 1, "dup", "unique" )
```

**Calculated Column - using ALLEXCEPT -Preferred Than COUNTX - this doubles as a measure too**

```
isDup2? =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table'[date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[PMTNo], 'Table'[val] )
)
```

[image: Calculated column]

**Measure**

```
Measure =
VAR _surrogateID =
    MAX ( 'Table'[PMTNo] ) & MAX ( 'Table'[val] )
        & MAX ( 'Table'[date] )
VAR _count =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTX ( 'Table', _surrogateID ) )
RETURN
    IF ( _count > 1, "dup", "unique" )
```

[image: Measure]

Comment: Appreciate your help! I used the calculated column because I need it for other purposes on the report I am working on. Thank you so much again for helping me as I am still learning and studying dax. I also have other question which hoping you can also help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72643690/sql-translation-of-if-statement-to-powerbi-dax-query

Comment: Hi. can you help me again on my other question please. Thank you.