# SQL translation of IF statement to PowerBi Dax Query

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm kinda new to DAX and PowerBi and I need to translate my SQL `IF` statement for whatever syntax is this on PowerBi to achieve the output I want.

Sql code I want to translate:

`IF (Payment.payment>0) AND (Account.PV = Account.GV) THEN 1 ELSE 0`

I want to make a calculated column on **Payment** table which will return **1** or **0** so that I can use this to filter all the records that meets my condition

`account_id` is the relationship of these two tables

Here is a sample data for reference: **Account** table

| account_id | pv | gv | due_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 100 | 200 | 08/08/2022 |
| 124 | 200 | 200 | 08/09/2022 |
| 125 | 300 | 800 | 08/10/2022 |
| 126 | 400 | 670 | 08/11/2022 |
| 127 | 500 | 500 | 08/12/2022 |
| 128 | 600 | 600 | 08/13/2022 |
| 129 | 700 | 1000 | 08/14/2022 |
| 130 | 800 | 760 | 08/15/2022 |
| 131 | 900 | 900 | 08/16/2022 |
| 132 | 1000 | 1000 | 08/17/2022 |
| 133 | 1100 | 2300 | 08/09/2022 |

Here is a sample data for reference: **Payment** table

| payment_id | payment_number | payment | payment_date | account_id | _test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 554321 | 1000 | 03/01/2022 | 123 | 0 |
| 102 | 554322 | 1200 | 03/21/2022 | 124 | **1** |
| 103 | 554322 | 1100 | 04/28/2022 | 124 | **1** |
| 104 | 554323 | 2500 | 05/04/2022 | 131 | **1** |
| 105 | 554324 | 3000 | 05/14/2022 | 133 | 0 |
| 106 | 554325 | 3000 | 05/14/2022 | 132 | **1** |
| 107 | 554322 | 1200 | 03/21/2022 | 124 | **1** |
| 108 | 554323 | 2500 | 04/05/2022 | 131 | **1** |
| 109 | 554328 | 3100 | 04/05/2022 | 128 | 0 |

Codes I tried but I can't help myself to find the correct way to do it correctly and return the output that I need

1. `_test = IF(Payments[payment]>0 && RELATED('Account'[PV])=RELATED('Account'[GV]), 1)`
2. `_test = IF(AND(Payments[payment])>0, RELATED('Account'[PV])=RELATED('Account'[GV])),1,0)`

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Please recommend what kind of syntax/function should be used in order to achieve the output or what would be the work around to use other than `IF` statement

Comment: Check out the `AND` syntax documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/and-function-dax

Comment: @paneerakbari I still can't get the correct syntax on how to execute it. I am having a hard time comparing the two columns which is on other table

Comment: Please edit your question to include the DAX syntax attempts that you have made, that will help us understand better where you are with it

Comment: @paneerakbari added the code I tried, please help..

Comment: The new syntax looks better, are you getting an error or is it returning the wrong values?

Comment: Let's try exposing each of those values one at a time: What is the value of each of COUNT(Payments[payment], SUM('Import'[PV]), and SUM('Import'[GV])?

Comment: @paneerakbari it is only returning me 0 value which I should expect a 1 on those data that passed my condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245665/discussion-between-paneerakbari-and-let-soo-gas).

Comment: updated the question with sample data for reference

Comment: It is still not clear what error you are getting and when this occurs. The syntax seems to be fine. Two questions: Is there an actual relationship in the model between the two tables? Are you using this code to create a calculated column in the Payments table?

Comment: @MarcoVos , "yes" there is a relationship between the two tables and it is the accountid. And "yes", I am creating this code on the payment table. I am expecting 1 or 0 output so that I can use it for filtering.

Comment: And the error you are getting is?

Comment: @MarcoVos, using the code on no.2, i'm not getting any error instead. it is giving me wrong output which I should expect 1 or 0

Comment: So what output are you getting? The syntax is not the problem, so without more info, it is very hard to help you.

Comment: Stack recommends that you provide the data in [table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) and not in pictures. This is the least that needs to be done by OP to help others help OP.  Also, clearly mention the desired output based on that data.

Comment: @smpa01
added the table format for reference. updated also the details of the post for better understanding on the output I need to achieve, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are facing with **`RELATED`** is that RELATED only works from 1 side to many side.

Meaning, that if you bring the axis from 1-side and perform a calculation on the many side the filter works perfectly. Take a look at the direction of the filter below. The direction of the filter tells you on normal circumstances, you should bring your axis from **`Account`** and whatever calculation you perform on **`Payment** table it will work out.

[image: s1]

But you are doing exactly the **`reverse`**. You are bringing the axis from **`Payment`** and hoping for **`RELATED`** to work. It won't cause the direction to be as such.

However, **`DAX is much more dynamic than that`**. If for whatever reason, you need to bring axis from many side  where you need to **still** filter on 1-side, you can define a reverse **filter** direction **on-the-fly (because DAX is magical)** without needing to change anything in the data model by using **CROSSFILTER**. With **CROSSFILTER** you are customizing the filter direction as such

`CROSSFILTER(<LEFtblcolumnName1>, <RIGHTtblcolumnName2>, <direction>)`

This is how, (with your given dataset)

```
Column = 
VAR cond1 =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Account[Account.pv] ),
        CROSSFILTER ( Payment[Payment.account_id], Account[Account.account_id], BOTH )
    )
        - CALCULATE (
            MAX ( Account[Account.gv] ),
            CROSSFILTER ( Payment[Payment.account_id], Account[Account.account_id], BOTH )
        )
RETURN
    IF ( cond1 == 0 && Payment[Payment.payment] > 0, 1, 0 )
```

[image: s1]

Comment: It solved! This code exactly gives the results I wanted! so that's the reason why I am struggling and getting the wrong output using related. thanks for explaining it very well. I will definitely apply it on the future when I encountered again like this. Appreciate your help, thank you so much again!